# Change line endings and encoding of file at the same time

Tags: unix, encoding, newlines

I have some files with Windows line endings and latin-1 encoding that I need to convert to unix line endings and utf-8.

Of course I can

```
for file in ./*.csv; do
    sed s'/^M//' "$file" > "${file}.bak"
    iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf8 "${file}.bak" > "$file"
    rm "${file}.bak"
done
```

But is there a commonly available tool that can do both of these things at once? Maybe this isn't the most efficient way. (Maybe iconv?)

Comment: I strongly believe the answer is "no", since those two tasks are quite different and it doesn't make sense to write a single tool to perform both tasks at once, particularly where unix philosophy is concerned. But hey, who knows when somebody is crazy enough...

Answer (score 0):

I would make some slight modifications to your script. First don't use `ls` in your `for` loop, use `*.csv` because the glob will handle non-printable characters and spaces in file names. Instead of using sed's inplace redirect to `$file.bak`. If `strings` is available on your system then replace `sed` with `strings`. And always remember to quote variables.

```
    for file in *.csv
    do    sed 's/^M//' "$file" > "${file}.bak"
         #strings "$file" > "${file}.bak"
          iconv -f -iso-8859-1 -t utf8 "${file}.bak" > "$file"
          rm "${file}.bak"
    done
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll update the question accordingly, but that doesn't really answer the question. Also that's a somewhat less explicit way of converting line endings, and a reader could be confused about the motivation for the line - will it work if the file contains Welsh accented letters like w circumflex?

Comment: Well, one tool may not be as efficient as two or more tools. My response was aimed at making your code more efficient. The glob should be much faster that using `ls`. `strings` blindly change carriage returns and carriage retrun/newlines to newlines. `strings` should be faster and if I was aware that your csv file's last line was terminated then I would have suggests using `tr` instead of `strings` .iconv` is the only tool I know for your purpose.